# LINQ asenumerable() function

Tags: linq

I am new to LINQ. my question is why do we use asenumerable() in query when we can get out answer without even using it. i want my concept to be cleared about asenumerable() function. please help.

Comment: [Read remarks on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx)

Comment: It still not making me clear about t. bcoz my query works even if i am not using .AsEnumerable(). I mean what if I wont use it.